# Smartphone Image sensor brands and utilising devices

Tags: data-request, products

I am seeking a list (or lists) of smartphone image sensor brands and which smartphone(s) they are used in.

So far, I have found the following page for Sony's [Exmor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exmor) image sensor range, there are lists of sensors and devices (phones and cameras) that employ that particular image sensor brand - but the lists are incomplete.